# Drupal 6 - Content profile and user management

Tags: drupal, user-management, drupal-rules

I have developed a system using Drupal 6. I have implemented user registration with content profile. Which means there is a functionality called company registration. It is creating a content profile with companies and a user account also after click register.

Once the profile and user account created both will be in pending status and I have implemented a functionality where the site admin can approve (using rules.) Once approved the content profile is accessible via front end.

But though the users status change rule is written (rule to change the pending user role to active member) the user is unable to login. Currently after approving the content profile the admin again need to go to the user account and activate it.

Can anybody help me to get this resolved please?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use Triggers with this, so that when a content profile is approved, the linked user profile will also be approved. You should be able to write an "Advanced" trigger for this.

https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/trigger